# Looking for a word that describes something that is of or relating to an empire

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes something that is of or relates to an empire?
I was thinking empirical, however empirical has to do with logistics and measurement. Here is the context of how I am trying to use this supposed word:

if something is of or owned by an empire, it would be ____, as something that is owned or is of a federation is federal.

Comment: You're free to [answer your own question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), but you need to do it in an *answer* (so I removed it from the *question*).

Answer (score 3):

How about *Imperial*

Imperial Airways was an airline serving the British Empire in the 1930s.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial) gives:

> "Imperial is that which relates to an empire, emperor, or imperialism."

Comment: Please provide a link to the Wikipedia article for the quote.

Comment: @jimm101 - Done. user266124 - Welcome to ELU. For external quotes attribution is essential, which you did so well done :). Links to that info are encouraged where possible, but not necessarily required (many good answers quote from printed dictionaries rather than their online counterparts).

Answer (score 0):

Something being owned by empire can be be empire's or Empire's (depending if you mean an empire (as a group of nations or peoples ruled over by an emperor) or the Empire (something that is referred to simply as Empire, like the first French Empire, for example). It's the same as something owned by Mike will be Mike's

For general adjective you can use Empire or empire (usually capital letter).Like empire styled building or empire treasury.

My knowledge stops here, maybe someone knows more.

Answer (score 0):

**Royal**

After consulting

> Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary of Current English

I get :

> of a king or queen

"Royal" , according to definition, is related to a kingdom, not an empire which might consist  of many kingdoms.

But later I looked up **The Collins Dictionary**

I get:

> Royal is used to indicate that something is connected with a king,
>   queen, or emperor, or their family.

---

> e.g. A royal person is a king, queen, or emperor, or a member of their
>   family.

So the conclusion is **ROYAL**.

I think **Imperial** is also fine.